# ¿Cómo agregar un valor en "cart_mini.php" de WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Tengo un pequeño problema y no he podido corregirlo. Es una adaptación que requiero hacer en el archivo de `"WooCommerce mini-cart.php"`, pero ni el soporte de *WooCommerce* me ha podido ayudar (dicen que corresponde al desarrollador del *template*) y el desarrollador del *template* lleva más de 5 días sin darme una respuesta.

Entonces estoy tratando de modificar el archivo por mi cuenta, y sí, estoy consciente de que no es el mejor camino, pero es necesario que temporalmente salga del bache donde estoy por ahora.

Bueno, el problema es el siguiente: Tengo un *widget* del lado derecho que me muestra un resumen del carrito de compras, desplegando los productos que han sido agregados con información como el título, *thumbnail*, cantidad y precio con descuento o sin descuento. Al final me muestra un subtotal de estos productos. Pueden verlo en el siguiente enlace:

[image: Página web]

Lo que quiero agregar es, adicional a lo anterior, el subtotal por cada producto agregado al carrito, es decir, tomando como muestra la imagen anterior:

> título = Amaranto con fresa
>
> thumbnail = imagen del producto
>
> cantidad = 10 kilos
>
> precio = $75.00 $63.75 (el primero corresponde al precio sin
>   descuento, el segundo con descuento)

Todo lo anterior es correcto, sólo quiero agregar, por cada producto el total de este, en este ejemplo sería:

> total = 63.75 * 10 = $637.50

El código que trae el archivo `"mini-cart.php"` es el siguiente:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { 
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly 
} 

?> 

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart' ); ?> 

<ul class="cart_list product_list_widget <?php echo $args['list_class']; ?>"> 

    <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?> 

        <?php 
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) { 
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 
                $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 

                if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) { 
                    $product_name      = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 
                    $thumbnail         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 
                    $product_price     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 
                    $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); 
                    ?> 
                    <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mini_cart_item_class', 'mini_cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>"> 
                        <?php 
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf( 
                            '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>', 
                            esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), 
                            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ), 
                            esc_attr( $product_id ), 
                            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() ) 
                        ), $cart_item_key ); 
                        ?> 
                        <?php if ( ! $_product->is_visible() ) : ?> 
                            <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?> 
                        <?php else : ?> 
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_permalink ); ?>"> 
                                <?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . $product_name . '&nbsp;'; ?> 
                            </a> 
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_item_data( $cart_item ); ?> 

                        <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?> 
                    </li> 
                    <?php 
                } 
            } 
        ?> 

    <?php else : ?> 

        <li class="empty"><?php _e( 'No products in the cart.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></li> 

    <?php endif; ?> 

</ul><!-- end product list --> 

<?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) : ?> 

    <p class="total"><strong><?php _e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); ?></p> 

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' ); ?> 

    <p class="buttons"> 
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" class="button wc-forward"><?php _e( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a> 
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="button checkout wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a> 
    </p> 

<?php endif; ?> 

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_mini_cart' ); ?>
```

Entonces, no sé si me equivoque, pero no veo que sea algo tan complicado, es sólo traer un valor más, traté de modificar esta línea:

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_quantity', '<span class="quantity">' . sprintf( '%s &times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'], $product_price ) . '</span>', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); ?>
```

Multiplicando ``$cart_item['quantity'] * $product_price`, pero`product price` parece que me trae solo una cadena '$75.00 $63.75', es decir ambos precios juntos, traté de separarlos pero no funcionó (no sé por qué)...

Entonces quiero creer que hay alguna variable como `$cart_item['']` que contenga el precio con descuento y así poder utilizarla.